# Locking Emails on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, email

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. I use the build-in Email application to access my email from my internet service provider (so this is NOT gmail, outlook etc.).

I am often on the road and I need access to my emails. However, I want to maintain the confidentially of the emails i.e. I don't want anyone else to open and read my emails.

I know I can lock my phone but I prefer to only lock the email application. In this scenario, I have no problem with anyone accessing my phone and looking at photos etc. It is just that I don't want them to have access to my emails.

Is there a way to lock the email application only so that if I want to access my emails, I will have to provide a password etc.

The emails I am referring to above are business emails, so I need to keep most of them confidential.

Comment: I'd have thought on a business phone, it would be just as bad for people to access or delete your contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of apps that perform the function of restricting access to other apps. Simply head to Google Play and search for "[app locker](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app%20locker)".